# CSS and JS not loading on JSP servlet mapping

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, servlets

When I don't have a servlet attached to a `/` in servlet mapping

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ControllerServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

All my css and javascript frameworks are loading. However, when I added this part of code in web.xml, none of the css and javascript are loading. How do I ensure that the servlet knows that it is a css/js file instead of a method?

web.xml

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>jdbcURL</param-name>
        <param-value>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bookstore</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>jdbcUsername</param-name>
        <param-value>root</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>jdbcPassword</param-name>
        <param-value>12345</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ControllerServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>net.codejava.javaee.bookstore.ControllerServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ControllerServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <error-page>
        <exception-type>java.lang.Exception</exception-type>
        <location>/Error.jsp</location>
    </error-page>
</web-app>
```

ControllerServlet

```
public class ControllerServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private BookDAO bookDAO;

    public void init() {
        String jdbcURL = getServletContext().getInitParameter("jdbcURL");
        String jdbcUsername = getServletContext().getInitParameter("jdbcUsername");
        String jdbcPassword = getServletContext().getInitParameter("jdbcPassword");

        bookDAO = new BookDAO(jdbcURL, jdbcUsername, jdbcPassword);

    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        doGet(request, response);
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        String action = request.getServletPath();

        try {
            switch (action) {
            case "/new":
                //showNewForm(request, response);
                break;
            case "/insert":
                //insertBook(request, response);
                break;
            case "/delete":
                //deleteBook(request, response);
                break;
            case "/edit":
                //showEditForm(request, response);
                break;
            case "/update":
                //updateBook(request, response);
                break;
            default:
                listBook(request, response);
                break;
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            throw new ServletException(ex);
        }
    }

    private void listBook(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws SQLException, IOException, ServletException {
        List<Book> listBook = bookDAO.listAllBooks();
        request.setAttribute("listBook", listBook);
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("BookList.jsp");
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

jsp page

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>

        <!-- JS -->     
        <script src='static/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
        <script src='static/js/vue.min.js'></script>

        <!-- CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/css/common.css">
     </head>
<body>
    <center>
        <h1>Books Management</h1>
        <h2>
            <a href="new">Add New Book</a>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <a href="list">List All Books</a>

        </h2>
    </center>
    <div align="center">
        <table border="1" cellpadding="5">
            <caption><h2>List of Books</h2></caption>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Author</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>Actions</th>
            </tr>
            <c:forEach var="book" items="${listBook}">
                <tr>
                    <td><c:out value="${book.id}" /></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${book.title}" /></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${book.author}" /></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${book.price}" /></td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="edit?id=<c:out value='${book.id}' />">Edit</a>
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <a href="delete?id=<c:out value='${book.id}' />">Delete</a>                     
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </table>
    </div>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I believe following mapping is the culprit. 

     <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ControllerServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

because of this every url will be routed to the ControllerServlet. As you want your static resources directly returned by your web container and you don't want your controller server serve them, give some url pattern to your ControllerServlet. Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add your CSS files like below

```
<LINK REL="StyleSheet" HREF="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/CSS/style.css" TYPE="text/css">
```

So folder structure would be like below

[image]

You need to add your css/js files inside the `WebContent`